# Vue + Firebase storage image doesn't show

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage, vuefire

I'm new in Vue and Firebase. I upload image to Firebase storage successfully. But failed to display the image. Here I attache my code. If you can give me any other solution for display images. That will be great also.

**Template**

```
<tr v-for="service in services" v-bind:key="service['.key']">
   <img :src="getImgUrl(service.fileName)" width="50px">
   <td>{{service.service}}</td>
   <td>${{service.price}}</td> 
</tr>
```

**Script**

```js
firebase: {
  services: serviceRef
},
methods:{
  getImgUrl(img){
    var imgUrl = firebase.storage().ref('service_images/'+ img).getDownloadURL();
    return imgUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Does the request for the image look correct? What is the response?

Comment: FYI ~ [_"getDownloadURL() returns **firebase.Promise** containing string"_](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL). You need to change your code to deal with the asynchronous nature of the Firebase API

Answer (score 1):

Because `getDownloadURL()` returns a promise, I'd recommend implementing the `readyCallback` to populate a `data` object with the corresponding image URL for each *service*.

```js
data () {
  return {
    serviceImages: {} // start with an empty object
  }
},
firebase: {
  services: { // make this a config object instead
    source: serviceRef,
    readyCallback () {
      this.services.forEach(({fileName}) => {
        firebase.storage()
          .ref(`service_images/${fileName}`)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(img => {
            // use Vue.set for reactivity
            this.$set(this.serviceImages, fileName, img)
          })
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and in your template, something like

```
<img :src="serviceImages[service.fileName]"...
```

Comment: i use vuefire for display all services.
firebase:{
    services:serviceRef
  },

Comment: where I will use this code? into mounted or methods ?  
this.services.forEach(service => {
  firebase.storage()
    .ref(`service_images/${service.fileName}`)
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then(img => {
      this.servicesImages[service['.id']] = img
    })
})

Comment: can you please give me a complete code of how to display the image. then I will study it and understand it step by step later. but for now I need to display the image first

Comment: @user3733570 I'm not familiar with vuefire but you should add **all** relevant information and code to your question

Comment: @user3733570 after reading the vuefire documentation, I think I've found what you need

Comment: better if you can give me a complete code for display images with vue and firebase store. the code you sent Im confuse about where I will use the 2nd section

Comment: It would be better if you were able to take this information and apply it yourself

Comment: Yeah !!! it works finally .........Thanks man for your great great afford ..I was stuck with it from yesterday. Almighty bless you.